# Who is the girl with white hair that also wears a black thing over her eyes?

Tags: game-identification

She has white hair, a black rectangular thing over her eyes, and she's commonly found on the thumbnails of 'Gaming on Crack' videos

Here is an image:

[image: Gaming on Crack Thumbnail]

Comment: I can't believe I missed this question

Comment: @Vemonus If it makes you feel any better my first thought was actually 'Vemonus' :-)

Comment: Should've answered anyway and said "it's me"

Answer (score 25):

This is the character [2B](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/YoRHa_No.2_Type_B) - short for YoRHa No.2 Type B - from the game [NieR: Automata](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/NieR:Automata)

[image: 2b]

She also makes appearances in other games such as

> 1. Final Fantasy Brave Exvius
> 2. Valkyrie Anatomia: The Origin
> 3. SINoALICE

Comment: I didn't know she was in other games!

Answer (score 6):

That appears to be 2B from Nier:Automata.